# How to call custom jquery after authorized-net response magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, payment-methods, authorize.net

I want to set custom jquery after got the response from authorized.net in magento.

I'm trying with this code

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
],
function (
    Component,
    rendererList
) {
    'use strict';
    rendererList.push(
        {
            type: 'authorizenet_directpost',
            component: 'Magento_Authorizenet/js/view/payment/method-renderer/authorizenet-directpost'
        }
    );
    /** Add view logic here if needed */
    return Component.extend({});
}
);
```

I want to set jquery after got the authorized.net payment method form. i think this response come from

```
 Magento_Authorizenet/js/view/payment/method-renderer/authorizenet-directpost
```

files. can you please suggest how to set my jquery ?